# PC RAM and Graphics Card Upgradation

Tags: memory, upgrade, build

I don't have the money to build a PC, but I would like to upgrade my old one, at least from 4GB ram to 8GB and maybe the graphics card. My only issue is that I don't know what is compatible and what is not. Here are some pictures from CPU-Z.

[image: CPU_Z images]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pegatron Benicia Motherboard comes with four RAM slot.

- Each can support 2GB DDR2 with 667MHZ to 800MHZ.
- You can use 2GB * 4 RAM to each slot with SAME Speed
- If you are having existing Ram of 2GB you can make use of it. but only thing you have follow same speed is there all four RAMS. Make sure at final all four RAM are in same speed
- Currently in CPU_Z Shows One slot information you are using 1GB with 400MHZ (less speed). If scroll down we can see other slot information if you have more than 1 GB.
- If you want upgrade RAM to 8 GB. You have to Purchase four RAMs with 2GB DDR2 all with 800MHZ speed.
- Graphic Card is pretty good for existing Configuration 1GB with DDR5 with bus support of PCI-E 2.0 x 16. So we have check with support PCI-E 2.0 x 16 slot in NVEDIA.

Comment: Thank you!! But what about the graphic card? Any tips on that?

Comment: I have mention in answer

Comment: I found this ram, as you said 2GB DDR2 800MHz. http://www.fnac.pt/mp9569575/modulo-de-memoria-V7-V764002GBD-2GB-DDR2-800MHz?origin=GOOGLE_PLA&gclid=CjwKCAjw16HLBRBFEiwAElREqHuhWxtLzyAjuDxhWjcJCLeOBdFKyB0GhK7LVbFWF9IKVB03B3IGVBoCRPcQAvD_BwE

Comment: not able to open the site. sorry

Comment: http://prntscr.com/fvo74l

Comment: Good to go with 4 piece. what is your existing RAM in your system

Comment: https://mlm-s1-p.mlstatic.com/900401-MLM20313752166_062015-C.jpg

Comment: Image is not clear. More conversation in comment area leads to chat. Verify the answer again. Clarify your Doubt